# dpd-email / nodemailer wont attatch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer, deployd

Trying to att. a file using  dpd-email (its using nodemailer)
by examples in nodemailer (https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#attachments)

This just gives me a file of 'attachment-1.bin'   0kb of size

tried using diffrent post examples from the nodemailer site, but same result.

Using chrome postman

```
        http://localhost:99/email
        to:"asa@me.me"
        subject: "test"
        text: "test"
        attachments: [
    {filename: "test.tx"', content:"hello world", contentType:"text/plain"} 

]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In NodeMailer, `attachments` is an array of `attachment` objects. In your above code snippet though, you're setting `attachments` to an object instead of an array.

Taken directly from [E-mail Message Fields](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#e-mail-message-fields)

> **attachments** - An array of attachment objects

**Change**

```
attachments: {
  filename: 'text.bin', 
  content: 'hello world!', 
  contentType: 'text/plain' 
}
```

**To**

```
attachments: [
  {
    filename: 'text.bin', 
    content: 'hello world!', 
    contentType: 'text/plain' 
  }
]
```

Comment: attachments: [{filename: "test.tx"', content:"hello world", contentType:"text/plain"} ]

Comment: still just gives me attachment-1.bin